# How to "submit the policy compliant update"?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have updated my app on google play store, with a version that contains a big icon in the `xxxhdmi` version, so they gave removed the whole app

They said in the email

```
Next Steps

1-Make changes to your app icon to bring your app into compliance. Your app’s launcher icon size must not exceed 2048x2048.

2-Read through the Device and Network Abuse policy for more details, and make sure your app complies with all policies listed in the Developer Program Policies.

3-Sign in to your Play Console and submit the policy compliant update.

If approved, your app will again be available with all installs, ratings, and reviews intact.
```

So I had done the 1 and 2 steps, but can't find what to do with the last step

```
Sign in to your Play Console and submit the policy compliant update.
```

So my question is, how to **submit the policy compliant update**?

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your app in Android studio -> build.gradle for your app and change "versionCode
and versionName" values then generate a new release and publishing in your play store account

Answer (score 1):

just add a privacy policy in your app. Add a new screen containing your privacy policy and give a new update.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says your app exceeds the icon size defined 2048x2048. Use [Android Asset studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) to generate icons.